# Showing xml text and design by default

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.6

My Android Studio forced updated today and now. Whenever I open an .xml file (or reopen one), it opens it with the design ONLY (third option in the picture), it is simple to switch the view, but it gets very annoying to do it all the time and I cannot find any settings to change the default to design and text or just text. I marked the switch I am talking about in red. Anyone knows if it can be changed and how?

[image]
(In the picture it is switched to the desired setting, but every new file is opened as the third option)

Answer (score 0):

There is no setting to switch to default as this is the new features in new update but you can switch back to Android studio 3.5